# unable call ussd in react native

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation, ussd

We need to call **ussd** in the react-native app. We are trying to call directly **ussd** without redirect to the keypad
We tried

```
  npm install react-native-ussd --save(https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-ussd)
```

`Ussd.dial("*121#");` nothing happened this even it's not showing any error

We tried both ways but no luck. Can you anyone gaid to us. If is there any other alternative let us know.

Answer (score 0):

adding user permissions to android manifest, which naturally need permission to make calls in order to continue

```
<manifest>
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
<application>
```